# Error: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Task: to write a function for changing the timeframe on encodings.

Body of the program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from future_functions import *

# Load CSV Data

data = pd.read_csv('Data/EURUSDHours.csv')

data.columns = ['Date','open','high','low','close','AskVol']

data = data.set_index(pd.to_datetime(data.Date))

data = data[['open','high','low','close','AskVol']]

prices = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

hkaprices = prices.copy()
hkaprices['Symbol'] = 'SYMB'

HKA = OHLCresample(hkaprices,'15H')
```

, where `future_functions` is an attached file with a function.

The function itself:

```
def OHLCresample(DataFrame,TimeFrame,column='ask'):

    grouped = DataFrame.groupby('Symbol')

    if np.any(DataFrame.columns == 'Ask'):

        if column == 'ask':
            ask = grouped['Ask'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
            askVol = grouped['AskVol'].resample(TimeFrame).count()
            resampled = pd.DataFrame(ask)
            resampled['AskVol'] = askVol

        elif column == 'bid':
            bid = grouped['Bid'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
            bidVol = grouped['BidVol'].resample(TimeFrame).count()
            resampled = pd.DataFrame(bid)
            resampled['BidVol'] = bidVol

        else:

            raise ValueError('Column must be a string. Either ask or bid')

    elif np.any(DataFrame.columns == 'close'):
        open = grouped['open'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
        close = grouped['close'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
        high = grouped['high'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
        low = grouped['low'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()
        askVol = grouped['AskVol'].resample(TimeFrame).ohlc()

        resampled = pd.DataFrame(open)
        resampled['high'] = high
        resampled['low'] = low
        resampled['close'] = close
        resampled['AskVol'] = askVol

    resampled = resampled.dropna()

    return resampled
```

I receive an error:

> KeyError: 'AskVol'
>
> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

The data set can be taken following the link:
https://nofile.io/f/Q9AKjGbSUHd/EURUSDHours.csv

I understand that the problem is in dimensionality, but I do not know how to resolve it.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback? I.e. which line/reference to 'AskVol' is producing the error?

Comment: Yes, i posted the full traceback by reference http://freetexthost.com/isjx2keuoh

Comment: You should take some time and isolate out the source of your error. Here is how you should ask questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve